# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spitterDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jdbc, jndi

I am trying to access a JNDI `datasource` in tomcat using Spring's `jee jndi-lookup` tag.

The exception is indicating that I haven't registered my `datasource` correctly but I'm unable to figure out why not.

Here is my code:-

***service-context.xml***:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="spitter" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="/jdbc/spitterDS" resource-ref="true" />

</beans>
```

***webapp/META-INF/context.xml***:-

```
<Context path="/spitter" reloadable="true" cachingAllowed="false" antiResourceLocking="true">

<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<Resource name="jdbc/spitterDS" auth="Container" type="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="root" password="password"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spitter" />
</Context>
```

***web.xml***:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">

<display-name>Spitter</display-name>

<resource-ref>
    <description>Spitter DS</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/spitterDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:service-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and finally,

***MainController.java***:-

```
package spitter.mvc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {
    @Resource(name="dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHome(Model model) throws SQLException{
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();

        return "spitter";
    }
}
```

I am using `Tomcat 7` in `Eclipse kepler` for JEE developers. The exception when I start the tomcat server in eclipse:-

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of resource
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [jdbc/spitterDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].

I assume I have made a typo somewhere but cannot find it. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

`"/jdbc/spitterDS"` is not equal to `"jdbc/spitterDS"`.

In `service-context.xml` file,
Change

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="/jdbc/spitterDS" resource-ref="true" />
```

To

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/spitterDS" resource-ref="true" />
```

---

***Edit***:

> *Error creating bean with name 'dataSource':*

As per documentation:

> *... in the `@Resource(name="jdbc/Foo") DataSource ds;` annotation, the
>   global JNDI name is `jdbc/Foo`.
>
>   ...
>
>   The @Resource annotation in the application code looks like this:
>
>   `@Resource(name="jdbc/helloDbDs") javax.sql.DataSource ds;`*

Change:

```
@Resource(name="dataSource")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

To:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/spitterDS")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

***Refer To***: [***Using the Java Naming and Directory Interface***](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/jndi.htm).

Comment: Thanks. I made the change but I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: Can you check with `Resource(name="jdbc/spitterDS")` or `Resource(id="jdbc/spitterDS")`. I am not sure about the second option.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Resource definition is correct. If I change it to another name it complains it can't find a bean with that name. There is also no id attribute for @Resource. I think the problem is something to do with the datasource not registering property in jndi i.e the context.xml configuration. Or if its the tomcat setup in eclipse causing problems. Not sure.

Comment: Without using a `@Resource` annotation, are you able to load the datasource, if not in that bean, from anywhere else?

Comment: As per documentation, your reference to resource in the java code is wrong. Please check my updated answer, with correction suggested.

Comment: It seems that cleaning out the tomcat working directory fixed the problem! Appreciate the help Ravinder anyways :-)

Comment: It worked with your original values on dataSource references?

Comment: yes that's right. What I did to fix the problem was clean the tomcat working directory and change the BasicDataSource to a javax.sql.DataSource. It didn't seem to like BasicDataSource for some reason. Don't know why it didn't say anything in the logs.

Comment: Ravindra - Could you please guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465272/caused-by-javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-name-jdbc-baeldungdatabase-is-n ?

Answer (score 2):

I faced off this problem too, in my case I missed a WARN from tomcat log, I didn't include the jar for

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory 

commons-dbcp-x.x.jar
commons-pool-x.x.x.jar
commons-lang-x.x.x.jar
```

Fixed this, all runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to increase the setting in my.cnf

    `max_connections = 120`

I get the impression that any misconfiguration of mysql will give this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I got same exact error. But for me following was missing from Resource

```
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
```

After adding that, everything worked perfectly.